# Viewing the captured content of the webcam live

Tags: python, camera, opencv, webcam

How can I view the captured content of my webcam on Linux/Raspberry?
I dont want to share it, only view the content live on my monitor.

On windows Logitech has an official program where I can preview the content live. Windows has also the built-in camera program.

How does it work on Raspberry/Linux?
I would like to buy the Logitech C922.

I have read recently a discussion about C922 here:
[Get h264 from Webcam Logitech C922](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63798/get-h264-from-webcam-logitech-c922)
<- Will this thing affect my purpose/aims or it has no affect? (I did not fully understand that discussion)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using RaspberryPi-OS with a graphical user interface and the screen is directly connected to the Pi via HDMI.

Just install VLC media player by typing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y vlc
```

in the Pi's terminal.

Now, open VLC and go to *Media -> Open Capture Device* and select your videodevice.

Comment: Thank you. I would like increase the contrast and thresholding the live captured content. This could be done with opencv python. Can I use VLC to show the 'modified' content or VLC will show the original captured content?

Comment: I don't know opencv but I think there would be a second videodevice to chose. Let's say /dev/video0 is your webcam with raw data, then you modify it using opencv and output it to /dev/video1. So you will have to chose /dev/video1 as input in VLC.

Comment: Vlc does have various effect filters and adjustments.  You can likely even build your own mod if you really want to.